How to have two hosts of same nginx docker container communicate?
I have a docker environment for working locally with two php-fpm containers (php 8.2 and php 7.4) and an nginx web server.
Since I have multiple applications, which run on different versions of php, I created a .conf file in nginx for each application and determine which version of php-fpm is to be used in the fastcgi-pass directive.
My problem is, I have two specific applications that are a frontend-client and an api. I have each of their hosts configured in nginx and I can access them with their configured URL like normal. But, whenever I need to make them communicate with each other, It doesn't work.
Calling api.localhost from inside the client.localhost application does not work and gives me the error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
So, what should I change, to make the api.localhost host visible to the client.localhost application? Considering they're both being ran by the same nginx container?
This is my conf files (only difference between each file is the php version, server name and root):
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name api.localhost;
    root /var/www/html/api/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php82:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
}


This is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx

  php82:
    build:
      context: php
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: 8.2
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts: 
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=host.docker.internal
      DEBUG: 1

  php74:
    build:
      context: php
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: 7.4
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
    extra_hosts: 
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=host.docker.internal
      DEBUG: 1

I tried using the extra_hosts directive in the docker-compose.yml but, to no success so far

Are the two containers building the exact same application, but just with different PHP versions?  Where exactly is the HTTP call being initiated from?  I don't see anything in your setup that would create a DNS name either api or client; where do these names come from?

The containers are not building the application itself, just the webserver, then there's a bind volume mounting the /var/www/html folder from my computer (where I clone the repos) to the /var/www/html inside the nginx container where I point to the root of each hosts.
They are not the same application, one is an api and the other is a frontend php application

For future reference, I solved it.
The problem is actually on curl itself.
For some reason curl auto resolves all domains ending with .localhost to 127.0.0.1, which in this scenario, breaks the funcionality as 127.0.0.1 inside the fpm-container points to the container itself, while the api.localhost domain was supposed to be pointed to the nginx container.
The solution is to use a different domain for local development like api.dev (will need to map it on your /etc/hosts) and use network aliases on the nginx container so that the php-fpm container can recognize that alias as the nginx container.
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.dev

